# 'Dtrace' error . Cocos2d-iphone 3.3 + SpriteBuilder + Chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, spritebuilder

I was making a game, ran it many times and it worked just perfect.Once this issue appeared, I can't even understand what was the reason.Missing any files? Cocos2d-iphone 3.3 + SpriteBuilder + Chipmunk

```
 /Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/external/Chipmunk/xcode/build/Chipmunk7.build/Debug-iphoneos/ChipmunkStatic-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/cpSpace.d:1: expected predicate and/or actions following probe description
```

[image]

Comment: Does this error go away if you restart Xcode, then do a Project -> Clean (hold option: Clean Build Folder)?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Cleaning doesn't help. Well, the issue disappears right after cleaning but appears again every time I try to run it.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D First it seemed to me, that I deleted some important files accidentally. I made a new project and copied all code and files exactly, but got just the same. I have also updated OS X, SpriteBuilder and Xcode. Can it be a bug of cocos2d 3.2 - 3.3?